# How to Minify .net AXD Resources

Tags: c#, asp.net, yui-compressor

I am working on a big .NET project. I am currently creating an automated minifier for JS and CSS files using YUI compressor. After doing some research, I found that the heaviest files in the project are actually .NET resources (Like MS ajax file). They are very big and unminified.

I am wondering, is there any way to minify them?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean ASP .Net?  This is important because .Net is merely a framework where it would be something ASP that would actually parse programmatic conditions into static output.

Comment: Yes, It's ASP .net, sorry for ambiguity.

Comment: I am also looking for solution for this, but so far I have found no feasible solution.
Two possibilities that I have considered are:
1) do not use the standard asp.net js - this means remove all ClientScript.RegisterXXX in the project and use custom mechanism
2) Replace the WebRessource.axd handler in the config file with your implementation, that does the same + compression.
Both options aren't applyable to my project, so if you find something else I will be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep - there's definitely a way to minify and/or combine any JavaScript and/or Cascading Style Sheets for your ASP.NET application.

But before I drop some links, etc... if you're using some of the major JavaScript framework's, like jQuery, MSAjax, whatever.. they all usually have minified version available to download .. and [some of them are available on CDNs](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/announcing-the-microsoft-ajax-cdn.aspx) .. which means you don't need to minify/combine them in your solution.

[Here is a list of major JavaScript libraries cached on the MS CDN](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx).

Now, finally for some info about how to minify/combine ASP.NET solutions.

[This link has some documentation](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sample%20MSBuild.xml%20File&ProjectName=yuicompressor) about how to make an MSBuild.xml file which is used to defines all the configuration settings/options for YUICompressor.NET.

While [this link is a video I made](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TquPgn1AACk) about how to do this with TFS2008 and Continuous Integration.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compress JavaScript or any other type of files?

If you are looking forward to compress JavaScript files, you can actually go ahead and compress ASP.NET AJAX libraries as well. This is a standard practice and most large JS libraries are compressed prior to deployment.